# dired list files sorted by access time

Tags: emacs, dired

How can I list the output of this command

```
   ls -ltDR \`find . -maxdepth 4 -type f -name "*.org"\`
```

within dired-buffer.  The above command lists all org files sorted by access time.

Comment: See also: <http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredSortMenu>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First open dired buffer using *M-x dired*

**Sorting by access time in dired buffer**

You can change the sort command used to order the dired buffer.

To sort by access time...

*C-u s*

this will bring up a minibuffer and you type *-lutR*

The R will make dired recurse subdirectories

**Showing only .org files**

Following info from this thread here works:

http://groups.google.com/group/gnu.emacs.help/browse_thread/thread/acb20ee78c00e4ec#

(Andreas Politz)

Here is one way :

1. Mark all files you want to see with `%m'
2. Expression you need for .org files is *..org*
3. Inverse the marks via `*t'
4. Invoke `dired-do-kill-lines' with`k'
5. When done, Reset the listing with `g'

Wrapped up in a function :

```
(defun dired-show-only (regexp) 
  (interactive "sFiles to show (regexp): ") 
  (dired-mark-files-regexp regexp) 
  (dired-toggle-marks) 
  (dired-do-kill-lines)) 

(define-key dired-mode-map [?%?h] 'dired-show-only)
```

Comment: Hi Justin, 
 Thanks for taking a look. I am afraid I didn't quite catch your solution. For example ~/*.org doesn't list org files in subdirectories. I can see s s will sort files but I don't know how to change the search type to -lutR. 
I can use find-dired to list all org files. But I can't sort them because the sort expression happens to be        
  "find . -name "*.org" -exec ls -l<flags> {} \;"     
which isn't the same as  
  "ls -lutR `find . -name *.org  " 
Essentially the previous command doesn't sort by access time at all. 
  
-Sandeep

Comment: In my post above I say that s can change the sort, but you need to do C-u s to change the sort type. Try it and it will pop up a prompt for you.

Comment: Hi Justin, 
 Its lot clearer now. Thanks so much. I learned some new tricks along the way as well. But I am afraid I can not still make it work. The reason being that I cannot list/mark all org files recursively with %m. I tried find-dired method to list the files. But emacs refuses to sort the buffer of find-dired. 

-Thanks  
Sandeep

Comment: Hi Sandeep

What you do is open dired buffer, then change the sort method to -lutR first, as the R is what lists the directories recursively

Now you should be looking at all the files in the directory and its subdirectories

It's at this stage you mark all the .org files

Comment: Hi Justin,
 The above should work. But the issue is that I just have too many directories and files to list them all first and then mark the org files. The org files are themselves  very few. Would have been better to list only the org first and then sort only those.

But I do appreciate you looking so closely into this.  It was fun to figure this one out.

-Sandeep

Answer (score 3):

You want to use `M-x find-dired`, with a custom value for the `find-ls-option` variable.

find-dired:

> find-dired is an interactive compiled Lisp function in
>   `find-dired.el'.
>
> (find-dired DIR ARGS)
>
> Run `find` and go into Dired mode on a buffer of the output.
>   The command run (after changing into DIR) is
>
> ```
> find . \( ARGS \) -ls
> ```
>
> except that the variable `find-ls-option' specifies what to use
>   as the final argument.

find-ls-option:

> find-ls-option is a variable defined in `find-dired.el'.
>   Its value is
>
> ```
> ("-exec ls -ld {} \\;" . "-ld")
> ```
>
> Documentation:
>   Description of the option to `find` to produce an `ls -l`-type listing.
>   This is a cons of two strings (FIND-OPTION . LS-SWITCHES).  FIND-OPTION
>   gives the option (or options) to `find` that produce the desired output.
>   LS-SWITCHES is a list of `ls` switches to tell dired how to parse the output.

Comment: Two questions: How do I go into dired-mode on any buffer. There isn't  any dired-mode command. 
Second the output of find . -exec ls -ltu {} \; isn't the same as 
 the command listed above. So I don't think I can use find-dired  for the purpose.

Thanks  
Sandeep

Comment: Hey Sandeep, check my answer, it orders by access time. Your command line above isn't valid.